# How can Ordinals prove Zorn's Lemma for Uncountable Posets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It seems that many authors use ordinals to prove, by contradiction, Zorn's Lemma. So far so good.

My understanding is that the basic idea of such proof is to choose a chain in the poset, choose an element in the chain, index it with an ordinal, get the successor element under the partial order of the poset (i.e. smallest element larger than the previous), index that, and so on, so that the ordinals will eventually get exhausted, but that contradicts the definition of ordinals. (My (limited) understanding of the proof comes from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8Rv2PHxAwQ&t=288s) (proof starts at 4:47).)

What I don't get is how this idea of picking a next element translates to uncountable sets. If my poset contains $\mathbb{R}$ as a chain (my understanding is that there exists an ordering for which $\mathbb{R}$ is a chain, even if we can't formulate it), and I pick, say, $1\in\mathbb{R}$, then sure, the next element is some other real, and the next element of that some other real again, and so on; but how is this supposed to go through *every* real? I mean, if it could do that, wouldn't that contradict the uncountability of the reals?

Comment: We can not formulate a "well ordering" for $\Bbb R$. But the usual ordering of $\Bbb R$ is a chain

Comment: The injection is $from$ Ord, not $to$.  One defines a successor operation on $X$ (and this is where AC is used.) Then, one defines inductively a
weakly increasing sequence $(x_{\alpha})\subseteq  X$, indexed by the ordinals.

Comment: Note that Zorn's Lemma does not apply to $\mathbb R$ (with its usual ordering), because the chain $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ has no upper bound.

Comment: The point of the proof that you can always choose a *greater* element using *transfinite recursion*, let's say your poset fulfill the condition for the lemma and $\Bbb R$ is a chain, then you can take an element *greater* than any element in $\Bbb R$ and so on. To formulate the induction is a little annoying but the point is you always get an element greater than any element of the chain, call it the next ordinal and continue like this till you run out of ordinals

Comment: So we're using induction over a chain of chains ordered by inclusion? (as in $\mathbb{R}$ is an element of the chain of chains, and then $\mathbb{R}$ with an element greater than any element in $\mathbb{R}$ is the next element of the chain of chains and so on). If so, then what if this chain of chains is uncountable?

Comment: @BlondCafé: No, the induction is over ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zorn's lemma doesn't need to assign an ordinal to *each* element of the poset.

The usual proof from the Axiom of Choice constructs a injection from (an initial prefix of) the ordinals to *some* of the elements in the poset. Since the *range* of this injection is a chain, the premises of the lemma tells us that we can keep extending it as long as it doesn't contain a maximal element.

Since we *also* know (say, from Hartogs) that there is an ordinal we *cannot* inject into the poset, at some point before that ordinal the extension process must be forced to stop. But the only way it *can* be forced to stop is if we find a maximal element.

But generally all of the chains we consider during this process will be quite sparse; nobody says any of them need to hit everything.

> My understanding is that the basic idea of such proof is to choose a chain in the poset, choose an element in the chain, index it with an ordinal, get the successor element under the partial order of the poset (i.e. smallest element larger than the previous)

You don't need to get the *smallest* upper bound for the chain-so-far at any of the steps. Generally there is *no* "next" element among the upper bound. You're applying the choice function you got from AC to select *one* of them, but it won't be a "successor" in the partial order except perhaps by accident.

Comment: Does that mean that all chains in a poset are countable?

Comment: @BlondCafé No. Why would it?

Comment: My reasoning was this: From the answer I interpret that we find the maximal chain by starting with the range of an injection from the ordinals (i.e. this chain must be countable), and then expanding this chain step by step until it is a maximal chain (so this maximal chain is also countable). Thus every chain found this way is countable. (Is this correct so far?) Assuming that's the case, what made me think that all chains are then countable is thinking (probably mistakenly) that all chains can be seen as ranges from injections from the ordinals.

Comment: @BlondCafé: How do you get "so this maximal chain is also countable"? There's nothing that prevents it from being uncountable. You _start_ with a chain of length $0$ build it up to longer and longer chains until you can't extend it anymore.

Comment: @BlondCafé: Hmmm, do you somehow think that there are only countably many ordinals?

Comment: I thought everything one can make in a step by step process is countable, is that not so? I read that there are uncountable ordinals, but I'm not sure how that conflicts with the former idea. I suppose the problem is that the steps we extend the chain by are indexed by the ordinals and can thus be uncountable? If that's the case then I'll have quite some trouble trying to fathom ordinals.

Comment: @BlondCafé: Take for example $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal. It is also the set of exactly all the countable ordinals. If you agree that we can (possible) define $f(\alpha)$ for every _countable_ ordinal $\alpha$ with a step-by-step process, reaching $f(\omega_1)$ is just another step, same as the rest: $\{ f(\alpha) \mid \alpha\in\omega_1 \}$ is a chain and therefore has at least one upper bound. Select (using your choice function) one of those upper bounds to be $f(\omega_1)$. Done. Then continue with $\omega_1+1$.

Comment: This doesn't differ from what you do at every limit ordinal _on the way to_ $\omega_1$.

Comment: I think I finally understand. Thank you so much for your patience!